# UICollectionview Delegate and datasource not begin called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create UICollectionview programmatically,

but for some reason the delegates methods not begin called.
I can see in view debugger that the delegate and datasource is nil 
what can be the problem?
thanks

[image]

```
    class MyClass: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

             var contentView : UIView
             var collectionView : UICollectionView
             var images = [UIImage]()
            init(contentView : UIView, images : [UIImage]) {

                self.contentView = contentView
                self.images = images 

                let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
                layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: contentView.frame.width, height: 700)
                layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

                let cv = UICollectionView(frame: contentView.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

                cv.backgroundColor = .clear
                let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: .main)
                cv.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
                self.collectionView = cv

                super.init()

                self.collectionView.delegate = self
                self.collectionView.dataSource = self

                contentView.addSubview(cv)


            }
    }
```

Then I instantiate `MyClass` from ViewController :

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let images : [UIImage] = [...]
        let cv = MyClass(contentView: self.view, images: images)

        cv.startAnimation()


    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this class used? Why does it extend `NSObject`? Where is the `collectionView` property declared?

Comment: Why are the two properties `weak`?

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, I edited my code,  also `MyClass` extends `NSObject` because from my ViewController I instantiate object of class `MyClass` and pass the view

Comment: There is no reason for the two properties to be `weak` or to be declared with `!`.

Comment: Ok, I removed the weak and `!`

Comment: And? Does it work now? If not, you still need to update your question with how you use this `MyClass` class.

Comment: @rmaddy It's not working, please see my question update

Comment: Why are you creating a collectionview called cv but assigning the delegates to a collectionview called collectionview?

Comment: @GustavoConde it is the same thing..

Comment: @knic1ned how's that?

Comment: @knic1ned. Gustavo is right. `collectionView` does not seem to be initialized (its not tagged as an outlet). You create another collectionview `cv` but aren't adding it as a subview.

Comment: @GustavoConde breakpoint after `super.init()`, then check for `cv === self.collectionView`

Comment: @knic1ned - are you setting the frame of your collectionView?

Comment: ah - never mind, see it now... posting an answer in a minute...

Comment: The collection view needs to be an instance property of the view controller it resides in as it has been answered below. However, I would consider refactoring your code and simplifying this process because in my opinion you've made this more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view controller code:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let images : [UIImage] = [...]
        let cv = MyClass(contentView: self.view, images: images)

        cv.startAnimation()

    }
}
```

as soon as program execution leaves `viewDidLoad()`, `cv` no longer exists.

You want to keep that object around, so it can act as the delegate and datasource:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var cv: MyClass?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let images : [UIImage] = [...]

        cv = MyClass(contentView: self.view, images: images)

        cv.startAnimation()

    }
}
```